# Lisp code called from Java

Tags: java, lisp, clisp, jatha

Long story:

I am doing a project for my functional programing class, and I thought of writing an AI controller in Lisp, for the [Mario AI competition](http://julian.togelius.com/mariocompetition2009/).

I was looking over frameworks/libraries/ways of calling Lisp code from Java, or even better Lisp-Java intercommunication.

I have looked at [Jacol](http://jacol.sourceforge.net/), but it is old, and it does not compile fine for me.

My best choice so far is: [Jatha](http://jatha.sourceforge.net/).
It is really neat, although some lisp constructs are not yet implemented, one can easily define his own constructs. For example **mapcar** and **cond** are not implemented.
I have implemented my own **mapcar**, named **mapp** in Lisp like this:

```
(defun map* (f l r) 
  (if (null l)
      r
      (map* f (rest l) (cons (funcall f (first l)) r))))

(defun mapp (f l)
    (reverse (map* f l nil)))
```

Now I have a simple function that uses this, for example, a function that numbers how many atoms there are in a non-linear list

```
(defun myfunc (l)
  (if (atom l)
      '1
      (apply '+ (mapp 'myfunc l)))) 

(myfunc '(6 2))
```

This all works fine in **clisp**
Now to call Lisp code from Java I used **Jatha**. All one has to do is import the Jatha library in the java project and load a lisp file like this (ex):

```
import org.jatha.*;
import org.jatha.dynatype.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jatha lisp = new Jatha(false, false);
        lisp.init();
        lisp.start();
        LispValue file = lisp.makeString("X:\\lispproject\\test1.lisp");
        LispValue rez1 = lisp.load(file);
    }
}
```

While that code works fine in clisp, and other implementations, this code produces a StackOverflow

`run:
APPLY: fn = +, args = ((1 1))
S: ((+ (QUOTE 1) (QUOTE 1)))
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:242)
        at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:100)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2946)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispInteger.toString(StandardLispInteger.java:113)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:174)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:153)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toString(StandardLispCons.java:152)
        at org.jatha.dynatype.StandardLispCons.toStringAsCdr_internal(StandardLispCons.java:17`

So my question is, why does it do this? Is my code wrong? 
Is it a bug in Jatha? See for yourself, it doesn't take long to set up. 
Have you ever done something similar?
Do you know any other better ways to do this?  All I want is to call from Java some Lisp code, get it executed, and get back results computed by the Lisp code. 
Thanks.

[Edit] Fixed code, pasted something wrong.

Comment: Generally go for pure Java solutions, not Java with calls to native code.  Your life will be happier :)  In this case, a LISP running on theJVM.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ABCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/) is a Common Lisp implementation that runs directly in the JVM - possibly it is the best option to run Common Lisp side by side with Java.

Comment: This works perfectly and is what i was looking for. Thank you
For anyone that might find this of use i am posting a quick [crash course](http://www.automatous-monk.com/jvmlanguages/abcl/Armed_Bear_Common_Lisp.html) i found.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked into [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)?  It's a Lisp dialect that runs on the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: ...and http://java.dzone.com/tips/calling-clojure-java describes how to call Clojure code from Java.

Comment: Clojure looks preety good if i will find that it is backcompatible with Lisp, but for the moment i can't load even the most simple example, i keep getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate Clojure resource on classpath: X:\t.clj
`
and all i have is : `        RT.loadResourceScript("X:\\t.clj");` and the file is there.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that if i add the file in the Clojure directory works fine. There is some talk on the net about editing the pom.xml file

Comment: Sadly it is not Lisp backward compatible

Answer (score 2):

[FOIL](http://foil.sourceforge.net/) (Foreign Object Interface for Lisp) provides means to interact with Java and .NET programs.